# Embed image in mail Body using mailto function

Tags: javascript, angularjs, email, user-interface

I am using mailto function my requirement is like to embed image inside mail body

```
 $scope.generateMail = function () {
        var graph = document.getElementById('thumb_graphs_grp');
        html2canvas(graph).then(function(canvas) {
        var dataURL = canvas.toDataURL();
        var image = new Image();
        image.src = canvas.toDataURL("image/png");
        var imageHTML = "<img " + "src='" + image.src + "' img/>";
        var link = "mailto:mail@example.org?subject=Mail request&body="+ imageHTML;
        window.location.href = link;
    });
```

Comment: I want the image inside mail body but i am converting to data url is their any other way to append the image inside mail body?

Answer (score 1):

As stated in the [RFC2368](http://www.ietf.org/rfc/rfc2368.txt), it's not possible to include HTML with mailto:

> The special hname "body" indicates that the associated hvalue is the
>   body of the message. The "body" hname should contain the content for
>   the first text/plain body part of the message. The mailto URL is
>   primarily intended for generation of short text messages that are
>   actually the content of automatic processing (such as "subscribe"
>   messages for mailing lists), not general MIME bodies.